# How to make a quiz database using C++

Tags: c++

/*This is just the a part of the code that makes the database. Random access to questions will be generated in the same main function. What is wrong in this code? Please take a look and help*/

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

class ques{
void in_data(char qu[500],char p[25],char q[25],char r[25],char s[25],char      ans1)
        {
            std::strcpy(question,qu);
            std::strcpy(a,p);
            std::strcpy(b,q);
            std::strcpy(c,r);
            std::strcpy(d,s);
            ans=ans1;

        }

};

int main()
{

    ques q[2];
    q[0].in_data("what is 2+2","alpha","beta","gamma","delta","d");
    q[1].in_data("choose a","a","b","c","d","a");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what's wrong with the code if you don't explain what problem you're having. You'll need to edit your question to add more information to it, otherwise it could be closed as being "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

there are many errors in your code:

1- make `in_data()` public to be able to call it from outside like in your main otherwise you get compile-time error `accessing private data` remember members of a class is by default private whereas struct's are public

2- declare member data: question, a, b,... you are using them without declaring them.

3- you declared `in_data` to take a character as the sixth parameter while you pass to it a const character string in main:

```
q[0].in_data("what is 2+2","alpha","beta","gamma","delta","d"); // "d" is a constant character string not just a single character so change it to 'd'
q[1].in_data("choose a","a","b","c","d","a"); // look at in_data how was defined.
```

your code will look like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ques
{
    public: // make in_data public to use from outside
        void in_data(char qu[500], char p[25], char q[25], char r[25], char s[25], char ans1) // so pass eg: 'a' not "a"
        {
            strcpy(question, qu);
            strcpy(a, p);
            strcpy(b, q);
            strcpy(c, r);
            strcpy(d, s);
            ans = ans1;
        }
    private:
        char question[500];
        char a[25];
        char b[25];
        char c[25];
        char d[25];
        char ans;
};

int main()
{

    ques q[2];
    q[0].in_data("what is 2+2","alpha","beta","gamma","delta",'d');
    q[1].in_data("choose a","a","b","c","d",'a');

    return 0;
}
```

- Finally why don't you use `class string` as long as it is a must in your code instead of using arrays of characters?

Comment: thank you so much. Actually I copied only a part of the code so forgot some parts. the only error was related to const char. Thanks for reviewing.